# Using channels to find the fastest responder from a list of dns servers

Tags: go

I am trying to find the dns server  that responds the fastest to a dns request, from a set of servers, using channels.

This is my code. I am wondering if this is the right way to do it or can it be optimized?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan string, 1)
    resolvers := []string{
        "1.1.1.1",
        "1.0.0.1",
        "8.8.4.4",
        "9.9.9.9",
        "8.8.8.8",
        "4.2.2.2",
    }

    for _, server := range resolvers {
        go func(server string, ch chan string) {
            // dns client
            r := &net.Resolver{
                PreferGo: true,
                Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
                    d := net.Dialer{
                        Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(10000),
                    }
                    return d.DialContext(ctx, network, server+":53")
                },
            }
            _, _ = r.LookupHost(context.Background(), "www.google.com")
            ch <- server

        }(server, ch)
    }
    fmt.Printf("fastest is %s", <-ch)

}
```

Comment: you cannot guaruantee when which goroutine actually starts. So if this is a benchmark, the fastest may not be the actual fastest, it just might be the first one (or only one!) started. If this is just "i want a connection as fast as possible" kind of scenarion, i don't see anyway to do it quicker.

Comment: This leaks goroutines and won't work correctly on Windows, as there is no Go resolver implementation there.

Comment: I think it much depends on what you mean by fastest. In this case it will return the first one to response but it could be it was also the first goroutine to run or be scheduled so even if it maybe took longer than others it was still the first.

If you want to know the fastest you would have to time all and then get the one with the smallest time. You would also have to do it several times as there can be noise that cause fall results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could time the requests as following and print the exact timings.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

type benchmark struct {
    server   string
    duration time.Duration
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan benchmark, 1)
    resolvers := []string{
        "1.1.1.1",
        "1.0.0.1",
        "8.8.4.4",
        "9.9.9.9",
        "8.8.8.8",
        "4.2.2.2",
    }

    for _, server := range resolvers {
        go func(server string, ch chan<- benchmark) {
            // dns client
            r := &net.Resolver{
                PreferGo: true,
                Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
                    d := net.Dialer{
                        Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(10000),
                    }
                    return d.DialContext(ctx, network, server+":53")
                },
            }
            t1 := time.Now()
            defer func() {
                ch <- benchmark{server: server, duration: time.Since(t1)}
            }()
            _, _ = r.LookupHost(context.Background(), "www.google.com")
        }(server, ch)
    }
    for _, _ = range resolvers {
        b := <-ch
        fmt.Printf("server %s took %s\n", b.server, b.duration)
    }
}
```

The `defer` function will execute right after the `Lookup` function returns. For more info on `defer` you might like my blog. https://marcofranssen.nl/the-use-of-defer-in-go

This shows on my system timings as following.

```sh
$ go run main.go
server 9.9.9.9 took 49.836914ms
server 8.8.4.4 took 49.954711ms
server 4.2.2.2 took 49.996936ms
server 1.1.1.1 took 49.933049ms
server 8.8.8.8 took 49.94578ms
server 1.0.0.1 took 49.997141ms
```

You could e.g. put the results into a new benchmark slice which you could even sort based on the duration.

Another improvement to make is to run this benchmark multiple times and then take the average pr median for each server to get more accurate results over time.